# Running mssql-server-linux image in QUIET mode

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am using `microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest` MS SQL docker image.

It works fine, but outputs **dozens** of information, which I would be happy to omit. I couldn't find command line or environment options to run it in **quiet** mode, can anyone help me?

FYI command line is:

```
docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD="<BestPwd>" -e MSSQL_PID=Express -it microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

Just appending `-q` didn't help..

### UPD

I know containers can be run in daemon mode, what I need is to **reduce** log to warnings level and not removing it completely.

Also I would appreciate generic methods; which are NOT connected with `stdout` redirection or grepping / filtering output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-d` option to run the container in the background using below command.

```
docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD="<BestPwd>" -e MSSQL_PID=Express -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

If you want to see the logs then you can give `docker logs -f 'containerid'`

Comment: Yes, I know that, actually I run container with `docker-compose`. What I need is the way to **reduce** sql server output to lets say warning level.